# Get a file from iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have a program which creates some files in the application's Documents directory. I need to get those files from the device for debugging. How can I do it?

I am looking for a way to not need jailbreaking, partly because I have to figure out which million letter directory to attack, and partly because I will be talking to Cupertino in the near future.

I am sure this is a common issue. For example in games it's sometimes necessary to see the save-file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could access through Organizer : Xcode >  Window > Organizer

Or Access Programmatically.

Comment: Where in the organizer do you see the files in an App's Documents directory. I can't see the place.

Programmatically is unrealistic because of at least two reasons
1. I'd have to write lots of code to somehow send the file out of the device. Generally these files aren't expected to be exported from the device. So writing that code is a waste of time. Even if I had that reason 2 would cause real headaches.

2. The program might crash very early in loading, so it can't get to send the file. This is the problem I have.

Comment: Found it in Devices ->iPhone, then under the summary is the Applications tab which allow you to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Look at PhoneDisk @ www.macroplant.com

Answer (score -1):

If it's a jailbroken device you could [easily connect and transfer using SSH](http://www.simonblog.com/2009/05/17/how-to-use-ssh-to-transfer-file-on-iphone/).

Comment: I don't know why someone would vote down on my answer, BUT in case you guys are not aware, jailbreaking the iPhone is now perfectly legal in the US: http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/07/26/us_government_legalizes_iphone_jailbreaking_for_unauthorized_apps.html